# How to show different content when rotating a div

Tags: html, css, rotation, hover, transform

I'm trying to code a way to rotate a `div` on mouse hover and show a different content than before.

An example can be seen here: [www.possibile.com](http://www.possibile.com)

And here is my code for what I'm trying to do:

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.rotate {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
.rotate:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.rotate:hover > p.front {
  display: none;
}
p.rear {
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.rotate:hover > p.rear {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="rotate">
    <p class="front">This is a div to rotate.</p>
    <p class="rear">
      This is the div rotated.
    </p>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLLLsjLd/1/

The problem with my code is that whenever I hover upon the `div`, it shows the "rear" p at the beginning of the rotation and not in the end.

Any help?

Comment: Ishimdar your answer definitely worked! Thank you very much, very helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLLLsjLd/2/)

```
 body {
    background: #ecf0f1;
}
ul {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 120px auto;
}
li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;    
}
div {
    color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;    
    backface-visibility: hidden;    
}
.front {
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 210px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #e3e3e3;
}
li:hover > .front{
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);    
}
li:hover > .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);    
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);    
    background: #34495e;
}
#box1 {
    background: red;
}
```